# how to call django function

Tags: html, django, forms

i created a form which takes user input and then perform a computation function in excel. i have written all the code but having trouble in using that function. below is the view.py function code

```
def dpr(request):
    def report():
        userdate_date = request.POST.get('num1')
        userpath = request.POST.get('num2')
        # add = f'your num is {num1} and {num2}
        path = r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\Sale detail sheet'
        userpath1 = f'SALE DETAIL SHEET {userpath.upper()} 2020'
        abc = os.path.join(path, userpath1+'.xlsx')
        customers1 = [20,31,28,27,17,46,18,13,15,14,37,100125]
        customers2 = [100051,100062,100072,100087,100071,100070]
        customers3 = [100057,100056,100066,100068,100086,100091,100103,100126,100131,100145,100150,100152,100140,100165,100180]
        x = datetime.datetime.now()
        month = x.strftime("%B")
        df = pd.read_excel(open(abc, "rb"), sheet_name= month.upper() ,index_col=None, header=  None)
        tarik = userdate_date
    #  program for sumifs and countifs for customers1 and appending data to Dpr
        sum_list1 = []
        count_list1 =[]
        for i in customers1:
            ab = df[df[2] == i]
            a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
            b= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).count()
            sum_list1.append(round(a,2))
            count_list1.append(b)

        app = xlwings.App(visible=False)
        wb = app.books.open(r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\DAILY REPORT\DAILY REPORT FORMAT.xlsx')  
        # wb = xlwings.Book(r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\DAILY REPORT\DAILY REPORT FORMAT.xlsx')
        # xlwings.App().visible=False
        ws = wb.sheets['DPR']
        ws.range('E7').options(transpose=True).value = count_list1
        ws.range('F7').options(transpose=True).value = sum_list1

    #  program for sumifs and countifs for customers2 and appending data to Dpr
        sum_list2 = []
        count_list2 =[]
        for i in customers2:
            ab = df[df[2] == i]
            a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
            b= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).count()
            sum_list2.append(round(a,2))
            count_list2.append(b)

        ws.range('E20').options(transpose=True).value = count_list2
        ws.range('F20').options(transpose=True).value = sum_list2

    #  program for sumifs and countifs for customers3 and appending data to Dpr
        sum_list3 = []
        count_list3 =[]
        for i in customers3:
            ab = df[df[2] == i]
            a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
            b= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).count()
            sum_list3.append(round(a,2))
            count_list3.append(b)

        ws.range('F27').options(transpose=True).value = sum_list3
        ws.range('E27').options(transpose=True).value = count_list3
            # print(sum_list3)
            # print(count_list3)

        dict1= {
            'F7' : 'E49',
            'F8' : 'E50',
            'F9' : 'E51',
            'F10' : 'E52',
            'F11' : 'E53',
            'F12' : 'E54',
            'F13' : 'E55',
            'F14' : 'E56',
            'F15' : 'E57',
            'F16' : 'E58',
            'F17' : 'E59',
            'F18' : 'E60',


        }

        for i,j in dict1.items():
            num1 = 0
            num1_new = ws.range(i).value 
            num2 = ws.range(j).value 
            ws.range(j).value = (num2+(num1_new - num1))


        dict2= {
            'F20' : 'E62',
            'F21' : 'E63',
            'F22' : 'E64',
            'F23' : 'E65', 
            'F24' : 'E66', 
            'F25' : 'E67', 
        }

        for i,j in dict2.items():
            num1 = 0
            num1_new = ws.range(i).value 
            num2 = ws.range(j).value 
            ws.range(j).value = (num2+(num1_new - num1))


        dict3= {
            'F27' : 'E69',
            'F28' : 'E70',
            'F29' : 'E71',
            'F30':  'E72',
            'F31' : 'E73',
            'F32' : 'E74',
            'F33' : 'E76', ##
            'F34' : 'E77',
            'F35' : 'E78',
            'F36' : 'E79',
            'F37' : 'E80',
            'F38' : 'E81',
            'F39' : 'E82',
            'F40' : 'E83',
            'F41' : 'E84',

        }

        for i,j in dict3.items():
            num1 = 0
            num1_new = ws.range(i).value 
            num2 = ws.range(j).value 
            ws.range(j).value = (num2+(num1_new - num1)) 

        wb.save()
        wb.close()     
    return render(request,'dpr.html')
```

below is the html page code which is dpr.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="dpr" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <b>Enter 1st num : <input type="text" name='num1'></b><br>
        <br>
        <b>Enter 2nd num : <input type="text" name='num2'></b><br>
        <input type="submit">


</body>
</html>
```

my main aim is that when user gives the input in the html and press submit button and then this report function must get called and do the needful. the issue is how to use the dpr function in request rendering.

Comment: you have to check if the request is post in your function

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132210/what-does-request-method-post-mean-in-django/34131288

Comment: you can check if the request is post then process your excel logic else render the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the request is `POST` or `GET`. For `POST` request, process the data and render the page. For `GET` request, just render the page.

```py
def dpr(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        userdate_date = request.POST.get('num1')
        userpath = request.POST.get('num2')
        # add = f'your num is {num1} and {num2}
        path = r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\Sale detail sheet'
        userpath1 = f'SALE DETAIL SHEET {userpath.upper()} 2020'
        abc = os.path.join(path, userpath1+'.xlsx')
        customers1 = [20,31,28,27,17,46,18,13,15,14,37,100125]
        customers2 = [100051,100062,100072,100087,100071,100070]
        customers3 = [100057,100056,100066,100068,100086,100091,100103,100126,100131,100145,100150,100152,100140,100165,100180]
        x = datetime.datetime.now()
        month = x.strftime("%B")
        df = pd.read_excel(open(abc, "rb"), sheet_name= month.upper() ,index_col=None, header=  None)
        tarik = userdate_date
    #  program for sumifs and countifs for customers1 and appending data to Dpr
        sum_list1 = []
        count_list1 =[]
        for i in customers1:
            ab = df[df[2] == i]
            a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
            b= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).count()
            sum_list1.append(round(a,2))
            count_list1.append(b)

        app = xlwings.App(visible=False)
        wb = app.books.open(r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\DAILY REPORT\DAILY REPORT FORMAT.xlsx')  
        # wb = xlwings.Book(r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\DAILY REPORT\DAILY REPORT FORMAT.xlsx')
        # xlwings.App().visible=False
        ws = wb.sheets['DPR']
        ws.range('E7').options(transpose=True).value = count_list1
        ws.range('F7').options(transpose=True).value = sum_list1

    #  program for sumifs and countifs for customers2 and appending data to Dpr
        sum_list2 = []
        count_list2 =[]
        for i in customers2:
            ab = df[df[2] == i]
            a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
            b= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).count()
            sum_list2.append(round(a,2))
            count_list2.append(b)

        ws.range('E20').options(transpose=True).value = count_list2
        ws.range('F20').options(transpose=True).value = sum_list2

    #  program for sumifs and countifs for customers3 and appending data to Dpr
        sum_list3 = []
        count_list3 =[]
        for i in customers3:
            ab = df[df[2] == i]
            a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
            b= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).count()
            sum_list3.append(round(a,2))
            count_list3.append(b)

        ws.range('F27').options(transpose=True).value = sum_list3
        ws.range('E27').options(transpose=True).value = count_list3
            # print(sum_list3)
            # print(count_list3)

        dict1= {
            'F7' : 'E49',
            'F8' : 'E50',
            'F9' : 'E51',
            'F10' : 'E52',
            'F11' : 'E53',
            'F12' : 'E54',
            'F13' : 'E55',
            'F14' : 'E56',
            'F15' : 'E57',
            'F16' : 'E58',
            'F17' : 'E59',
            'F18' : 'E60',


        }

        for i,j in dict1.items():
            num1 = 0
            num1_new = ws.range(i).value 
            num2 = ws.range(j).value 
            ws.range(j).value = (num2+(num1_new - num1))


        dict2= {
            'F20' : 'E62',
            'F21' : 'E63',
            'F22' : 'E64',
            'F23' : 'E65', 
            'F24' : 'E66', 
            'F25' : 'E67', 
        }

        for i,j in dict2.items():
            num1 = 0
            num1_new = ws.range(i).value 
            num2 = ws.range(j).value 
            ws.range(j).value = (num2+(num1_new - num1))


        dict3= {
            'F27' : 'E69',
            'F28' : 'E70',
            'F29' : 'E71',
            'F30':  'E72',
            'F31' : 'E73',
            'F32' : 'E74',
            'F33' : 'E76', ##
            'F34' : 'E77',
            'F35' : 'E78',
            'F36' : 'E79',
            'F37' : 'E80',
            'F38' : 'E81',
            'F39' : 'E82',
            'F40' : 'E83',
            'F41' : 'E84',

        }

        for i,j in dict3.items():
            num1 = 0
            num1_new = ws.range(i).value 
            num2 = ws.range(j).value 
            ws.range(j).value = (num2+(num1_new - num1)) 

        wb.save()
        wb.close()
    # after processing the request, the same template will be rendered for POST request. For GET request, only template will be rendered.   
    return render(request,'dpr.html')
```

Comment: your suggestion worked and my report got generated. thanx a lot

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Create function `report(userdate_date, userpath)` and call inside main function. try this. (I have not made any change in code).

**Create your function**

```
def report(userdate_date, userpath):
        # userdate_date = request.POST.get('num1') ## No need 
        # userpath = request.POST.get('num2') ## No need
        # add = f'your num is {num1} and {num2}
        path = r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\Sale detail sheet'
        userpath1 = f'SALE DETAIL SHEET {userpath.upper()} 2020'
        abc = os.path.join(path, userpath1+'.xlsx')
        customers1 = [20,31,28,27,17,46,18,13,15,14,37,100125]
        customers2 = [100051,100062,100072,100087,100071,100070]
        customers3 = [100057,100056,100066,100068,100086,100091,100103,100126,100131,100145,100150,100152,100140,100165,100180]
        x = datetime.datetime.now()
        month = x.strftime("%B")
        df = pd.read_excel(open(abc, "rb"), sheet_name= month.upper() ,index_col=None, header=  None)
        tarik = userdate_date
    #  program for sumifs and countifs for customers1 and appending data to Dpr
        sum_list1 = []
        count_list1 =[]
        for i in customers1:
            ab = df[df[2] == i]
            a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
            b= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).count()
            sum_list1.append(round(a,2))
            count_list1.append(b)

        app = xlwings.App(visible=False)
        wb = app.books.open(r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\DAILY REPORT\DAILY REPORT FORMAT.xlsx')  
        # wb = xlwings.Book(r'\\10.9.32.2\adm\Ash\FY 2019-20\DAILY REPORT\DAILY REPORT FORMAT.xlsx')
        # xlwings.App().visible=False
        ws = wb.sheets['DPR']
        ws.range('E7').options(transpose=True).value = count_list1
        ws.range('F7').options(transpose=True).value = sum_list1

    #  program for sumifs and countifs for customers2 and appending data to Dpr
        sum_list2 = []
        count_list2 =[]
        for i in customers2:
            ab = df[df[2] == i]
            a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
            b= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).count()
            sum_list2.append(round(a,2))
            count_list2.append(b)

        ws.range('E20').options(transpose=True).value = count_list2
        ws.range('F20').options(transpose=True).value = sum_list2

    #  program for sumifs and countifs for customers3 and appending data to Dpr
        sum_list3 = []
        count_list3 =[]
        for i in customers3:
            ab = df[df[2] == i]
            a= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).sum()
            b= (ab[ab[6]== tarik][8]).count()
            sum_list3.append(round(a,2))
            count_list3.append(b)

        ws.range('F27').options(transpose=True).value = sum_list3
        ws.range('E27').options(transpose=True).value = count_list3
            # print(sum_list3)
            # print(count_list3)

        dict1= {
            'F7' : 'E49',
            'F8' : 'E50',
            'F9' : 'E51',
            'F10' : 'E52',
            'F11' : 'E53',
            'F12' : 'E54',
            'F13' : 'E55',
            'F14' : 'E56',
            'F15' : 'E57',
            'F16' : 'E58',
            'F17' : 'E59',
            'F18' : 'E60',


        }

        for i,j in dict1.items():
            num1 = 0
            num1_new = ws.range(i).value 
            num2 = ws.range(j).value 
            ws.range(j).value = (num2+(num1_new - num1))


        dict2= {
            'F20' : 'E62',
            'F21' : 'E63',
            'F22' : 'E64',
            'F23' : 'E65', 
            'F24' : 'E66', 
            'F25' : 'E67', 
        }

        for i,j in dict2.items():
            num1 = 0
            num1_new = ws.range(i).value 
            num2 = ws.range(j).value 
            ws.range(j).value = (num2+(num1_new - num1))


        dict3= {
            'F27' : 'E69',
            'F28' : 'E70',
            'F29' : 'E71',
            'F30':  'E72',
            'F31' : 'E73',
            'F32' : 'E74',
            'F33' : 'E76', ##
            'F34' : 'E77',
            'F35' : 'E78',
            'F36' : 'E79',
            'F37' : 'E80',
            'F38' : 'E81',
            'F39' : 'E82',
            'F40' : 'E83',
            'F41' : 'E84',

        }

        for i,j in dict3.items():
            num1 = 0
            num1_new = ws.range(i).value 
            num2 = ws.range(j).value 
            ws.range(j).value = (num2+(num1_new - num1)) 

        wb.save()
        wb.close()
```

**Use the function**

```
def dpr(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            userdate_date = request.POST.get('num1')
            userpath = request.POST.get('num2')
            if userdate_date and userpath:
                report(userdate_date, userpath)

        return render(request,'dpr.html')
```